# How to pass a overloaded function pointer with a template data type?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, stdvector, function-templates

In the below **code** I want to create a function `count` which counts the number of **integers/strings** which qualifies a match criteria from a *vector of integers/strings*.

But I am not clear about how to write the function definition.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool match(int x) {
    return (x % 2 == 0);
}

bool match(string x) {
    return (x.length <= 3);
}

template <typename T>
int count(vector<T>& V, bool (*test)(<T>))
{
    int tally = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++) {
        if (test(V[i])) {
            tally++;
        }
    }
    return tally;
}

int main() 
{
    vector <int> nums;
    vector <string> counts;
    nums.push_back(2);
    nums.push_back(4);
    nums.push_back(3);
    nums.push_back(5);
    counts.push_back("one");
    counts.push_back("two");
    counts.push_back("three");
    counts.push_back("four");
    cout << count(nums, match) << endl;
    cout << count(counts, match) << endl;
}
```

How should the prototype be written ? I realize the error is at the line

```
int count (vector<T> &V , bool (*test)(<T>) )
```

Comment: `bool (*test)(<T>)` -> `bool (*test)(T)`, also `(x.length <= 3);` -> `(x.length() <= 3);`

Comment: please include the error in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function pointer type is

```
<return-type>(*function-pointer-identifier)(<argument-types>)<other specifiers>
```

Meaning, you need to remove the extra `<>` from the `count` function and you are good to go.

```
template <typename T>
int count(std::vector<T>& V, bool (*test)(T))
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or you could provide a template type alias for the function pointer type, which might make simpler to read

```
template <typename T>
using FunPtrType = bool (*)(T); // template alias

template <typename T>
int count(std::vector<T>& V, FunPtrType<T> test)
{
   // ...
}
```

**([See a demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/39j75xp79O1lgqEG))**

---

Side notes

- You have a typo in calling [`std::string::length`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) function.

  ```
  bool match(std::string x)
  {
     return x.length() <= 3; // missing () here
  }
  ```
- Also, have a look at the
  ([Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))